# how to add an arrow at the top of current timeline in vis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

I am currently using vis.js to create a time line. I need to put an arrow at the top of the current timeline. But I do not know how to get the correct location of the top of current time. Any helps are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is what I like to have

[image]

Here is the code I need to work on https://jsfiddle.net/gbdjbdhv/15/

```
var options = {
showCurrentTime: true,
orientation: {axis: 'both', item: 'top'}, 
height: 400,
margin: {
axis: 100
}
};
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines after your script.
    var lbl = document.createElement("label");
    lbl.setAttribute("style","margin-left:-10px;color:red;font-size:50px;line-height:35px;")
    lbl.innerHTML = "^"
    timeline.currentTime.bar.appendChild(lbl);

find fiddle here: gbdjbdhv/16/

Comment: AB Udhay: You are so creative! This works! Thanks you so much!